# Start Spring State Machine with HTTP call

Tags: java, spring-boot, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I want to trigger the Spring State Machine model loaded from Papyrus with an HTTP POST.
If I send let's say `{"state_machine":"START"}`over HTTP I would like to start the predefined state machine model. Is this possible? Or looking from different view, is it possible to create and run REST API inside the Spring State Machine model?

I'm using Spring Boot with Spring State Machine dependency.
There is defined endpoint on Swagger to send HTTP POST to Service class.

It is based on [this project](https://github.com/joergi/uml-spring-state-machine) where you can check all the code for State Machine/s because I basically just want to integrate HTTP call to it.

I'm getting NullPointerException considering Spring Statemachine at Service class for line 65 which is `stateMachineOne = this.stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine("machineone");`. Here is full exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at test.umlspringstatemachine.SSMService.RunSSM(SSMService.java:65)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ObjectHelper.invokeMethodSafe(ObjectHelper.java:372)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:494)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:316)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:286)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractBeanProcessor.process(AbstractBeanProcessor.java:146)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:81)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:780)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:688)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:181)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:62)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:167)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:388)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
        at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41)
        at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doExecute(CamelServlet.java:319)
        at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:214)
        at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:130)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Change that I made from that project is that I removed next part of code from `UmlSpringStateMachineApplication.java` so the State Machine doesn't start when I start the whole app:

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        synchronized (stateMachineOne) {
             stateMachineOne.getExtendedState().getVariables().put("foo", "machine1");
             stateMachineOne.start();
        }
       
        synchronized (stateMachineTwo) {
            if(stateMachineOne.isComplete()) {
                stateMachineTwo.getExtendedState().getVariables().put("foo", (String)stateMachineOne.getExtendedState().getVariables().get("foo"));
                stateMachineTwo.start();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Inside the Service class I have something like this below, but I get null exception like the Spring State Machine context or something is missing. I would like to `stateMachineOne.start();` once the `START` from HTTP POST is received.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.statemachine.StateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineFactory;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SSMService {

    @Autowired
    private StateMachineFactory<String, String> stateMachineFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StateMachine<String, String> stateMachineOne;

    public SSMService() {
    }

    public void TriggerSSM(Exchange exchange) {

        Message camelMessage = exchange.getIn();

        ObjectMapper mapObject = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> mapObj = mapObject.convertValue(camelMessage.getBody(), Map.class);

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(mapObj);

            String state_machine= json.getString("state_machine");

                if (state_machine.equals("START")) {

                    stateMachineOne = this.stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine("machineone");
                    stateMachineOne.getExtendedState().getVariables().put("foo", "machine1");
                    stateMachineOne.start();

                }
            }

        } catch (JsonProcessingException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

This is the config class:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnableStateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineModelConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.model.StateMachineModelFactory;
import org.springframework.statemachine.listener.StateMachineListener;
import org.springframework.statemachine.listener.StateMachineListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.state.State;
import org.springframework.statemachine.uml.UmlStateMachineModelFactory;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnableStateMachineFactory;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
//@EnableStateMachineFactory
@EnableStateMachine(name="stateMachineOne")
public class StateMachineOneConfig extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {

    Logger log;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<String, String> config) throws Exception {
        config.withConfiguration().autoStartup(false).listener(listener1()).machineId("machineone");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineModelConfigurer<String, String> model) throws Exception {
        model.withModel().factory(modelFactory1());
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> modelFactory1() {
        return new UmlStateMachineModelFactory("classpath:papyrus/StateMachine1.uml");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public StateMachineListener<String, String> listener1() {
        return new StateMachineListenerAdapter<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(State<String, String> from, State<String, String> to) {
                log.info("State 1 changed to " + to.getId());
            }
        };

    }

}
```

This is pom.xml file with dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Camel - OpenAPI - Spring State Machine</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring.boot-version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring.boot-version>
        <jackson.swagger.version>2.12.0</jackson.swagger.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>test.umlspringstatemachine.UmlSpringStateMachineApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring Boot BOM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Camel BOM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-uml</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rest-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rest-swagger-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-swagger-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.51.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.42</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- OWASP Dependency Check - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <format>XML</format>
                    <outputDirectory>${dependency.check.report.dir}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What problems are you running into specifically? I'm not familiar with the Spring State Machine, but you can add a `private boolean isEnabled` flag to any service you're using and have it changed based on what you receive in the REST call. Or you can @Lazy initialize it on demand.. I mean there are several approaches to this, but I don't think I understand your constraints correctly.

Comment: I'm getting NullPointerException when trying to start the Spring State Machine.

Comment: In that case you should add the details of the exception to the question.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the question with the exception.

Comment: 1) which line corresponds to ln 65 from the stack trace showing a Nullpointer? 2) what are the dependencies you have in your project @SP. ?

Comment: @DanielVilas-Boas I'm getting NullPointerException considering Spring Statemachine at Service class for line 65 which is `stateMachineOne = this.stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine("machineone");`. I've updated the question with pom.xml file containing dependencies.

Comment: you mind trying to attach these two to your app?

"org.springframework.statemachine:spring-statemachine-autoconfigure"
 "org.springframework.statemachine:spring-statemachine-data-jpa"

Comment: I've added these two dependencies, but still getting the same error. I think there is a problem with connecting the stateMachine defined in the Service class with the context for StateMachine or something in that direction, but I don't have enough experience to figure out how to create the necessary connections.

Comment: yea, it seems like your context it not wiring up properly. Do you have a repository that I can clone to take a look later?

Comment: Yes. You can access it on [GitHub](https://github.com/SP-10663172/rest-spring-state-machine-papyrus).

Comment: Took a quick look at your project and confirmed that the NPE is caused by not having a bean of "SSMService" when configuring your camel routes. Adding @component to that class makes it non-compilable because of machine one and two that are not properly injected. I will try to look more over the weekend, but would recommend you to investigate that section

Comment: I'm still dealing with this problem. I tried with `@SpringBootTest` and enabling the `@EnableStateMachineFactory` like on this [video](https://youtu.be/A-dVgRV5-Bw?t=1668), but it didn't help.

Comment: Also tried to implement it like on [this page](https://ozdinc-celikel.medium.com/state-machine-factories-while-using-spring-statemachine-55bd1e963af), but still getting NPE.

Comment: hey @SP. would you be able to give me access to push a change in your repository? I think i've came with a workaround. My github username is daanielvb

Answer (score 0):

I cloned your project and made several changes to have it working, the main ones can be listed here:

1- Added component scan to the main class to be able to find state machine configuration beans (including package rename). Got rid of SSM custom service and change to use your custom implementation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"uml.statemachine.*"})
public class UmlSpringStateMachineApplication implements CommandLineRunner 


@Autowired
    private SSMService stateMachineService;
```

2- boilerplate logic to aquire machines according to the type you want

```
@Component
public class SSMService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="config_one")
    private StateMachineFactory<String, String> stateMachineFactoryOne;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="config_two")
    private StateMachineFactory<String, String> stateMachineFactoryTwo;

    public SSMService() {
    }

    public StateMachine<String, String> acquireMachine(String id, String version){
        if (version.equals("one")){
            return stateMachineFactoryOne.getStateMachine(id);
        }
        else{
            return stateMachineFactoryTwo.getStateMachine(id);
        }
    }
```

3- Commented out StateMachineServiceConfig due to injection issues (you can look further)

4- Replaced for the factory annotation in your config classes

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory(name = "config_one")
public class StateMachineOneConfig
        extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {
```

5- In my case, the project was not compiling so I had to include few extra dependencies to your pom (might not be necessary)

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

You can find the list of changes in the repository I created to help you

https://github.com/Daanielvb/state-machine-papyrus-help

Hope that's helpful

Comment: Hi. I've downloaded the project from your repo and tested it. It still gives me NPE once I send a `START` message through the REST API. Can you please confirm that it works for you? If I run the app without changing your code, I get `Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:jar:2.6.0-M3: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:pom:2.6.0-M3 from/to spring-snapshots`. I added `<version>2.5.5</version>` to the spring-boot-maven-plugin in the `pom.xml`. Then the app starts, but I still get NPE.

Comment: I only tested it by running the main app. Can you give instructions on how to send the START message tru REST?

Comment: Yes. But before I give instructions, I see a small mistake that should be fixed. First, go to `state-machine-papyrus-help/src/main/java/uml/statemachine/swagger_examples/test/TestList.java` and replace `threat_name` variable with word `test`. Now start the app and open Swagger UI by entering `http://your-app-machine-ip:8080/swagger`. In the Swagger UI, select "/SSM/trigger" and press "Try it out". Then, inside `test_list` array, you will see `test`. Set `test` value to `START` and press "Execute". Now you should see the NPE error in the console of the Spring Boot app.

Comment: will take a look later, ty

Comment: have you maybe tested it?